# Calculate Time difference using powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to calculate Time difference between two time stamps in seconds

```
$starttime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
$endtime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")

$tdiff = $starttime-$endtime

Write-Output $tdiff.seconds
```

The above code throws the below error:

```
Cannot convert value "2022-02-10T11:40:07" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Appreciate, if any one can help

Comment: Note that for the difference in seconds, you want to use `TotalSeconds`. `Seconds` is only the second component of the difference (there are also `Hours`, `Minutes`, etc.).

Comment: @Anil Kumar - You are converting date to tostring. you can't perform substract on string values

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the date to String in the code. You can't perform the substract operation on string values.

Try below:

```
$startdate = (Get-Date)
$Enddate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $Enddate 
$diff.Days
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually much simpler than that.

```
$StartDate=(GET-DATE)

$EndDate=[datetime]”01/01/2014 00:00”

NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate
```

This is an example from Microsoft Devblogs
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-get-time-difference-between-dates-with-powershell/